# ¿como establecer valor de una variable js para usarlo en otras funciones?

Tags: javascript, variables

Tengo el siguiente código

```
function setubicacion()
{
    var estado;
    var municipio;
    var localidad;
    /*obtengo el id del productor del campo select*/
    var idproductor=$("#productor").val()*1;
    /*ejecuto consulta por ajax para obtener los valores de estado, municipio, localidad*/
    $.post("../ajax/planesvivos.php?op=setubicacion",{idproductor:idproductor},
    function(data,status)
    {
        data=JSON.parse(data);
        /*asigno las variables estado, municipio, localidad con el resultado de la consulta
hasta aqui funciona bien*/
        estado=data.estado;
        municipio=data.municipio;
        localidad=data.localidad;
        console.log(data);
        $("#estado").val(estado);
        $("#estado").selectpicker('refresh');
    });

    /*muestro el valor de las variables, pero me muestra null*/
    console.log("estado="+estado);
    console.log("municipio="+municipio);
    console.log("localidad="+localidad);
}
```

No se como hacer para que el valor de las variables estado, municipio y localidad lo pueda asignar dentro de la funcion post y poder usarla en cualquier otro lado dentro de la funcion setubicacion

EDIT1: lo que arroja la consola es lo siguiente:

```
estado=undefined
municipio=undefined
localidad=undefined
```

EDIT2: se agrego el console.log(data) y arroja lo siguiente:

```
Object { estado: "7", municipio: "3", localidad: "53" }
```

EDIT3: una posible solucion es crear 3 campos tipo hide en el formulario, guardar ahi el valor de estado, municipio, localidad. y luego en otra parte de la funcion (fuera de la funcion post) obtener los valores de los campos y así poder usarlos en otra parte, incluso fuera de la funcion setubicacion, porque ya estan en el dom.

Pero eso no es tan viable ni lo mejor, supongo. Espero sus respuestas al asunto.

EDIT4: he realizado lo del edit 3, pero no funciona, por alguna razon no actualiza los datos en el dom. Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Has intentado poner las variables como "globales" y pasarlas por referencia en la función?

Comment: como sería eso? es lo que no se.

Comment: No, olvídalo. Ese no es el error. Falla mía por no comprender al 100 el contexto de la pregunta

Comment: Que obtienes como salida en cada console.log?

Comment: ¿Podrías decirme que arroja el console.log(data)? siento que por ahí anda el error. A la hora de que haces persona.data.

Comment: Añade lo que te pregunta Edgar por favor

Comment: ya lo puse, en el edit 2

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puede hacer es usar una función flecha dentro del callback de respuesta del ajax, esta tiene ventajas con respecto a la declaración de funciones convencionales, como por ejemplo no tener restricciones de código encapsulado dentro de el.

```
   $.post("../ajax/planesvivos.php?op=setubicacion",{idproductor:idproductor}, (data,status)=>{
        data=JSON.parse(data);
        estado=data.estado;
        municipio=data.municipio;
        localidad=data.localidad;
        
        $("#estado").val(estado);
        $("#estado").selectpicker('refresh');
    });
```

Así la variables declaradas fuera del callback de respuesta del ajax las puedes usar dentro de la función y ya no estarían nulas.

```
console.log("estado="+estado);
console.log("municipio="+municipio);
console.log("localidad="+localidad);
```

Puedes consultas mas de la funciones flechas en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) de JavaScript.

Comment: sigue mostrando undefined para las 3 variables

Comment: Puedes ser la respuesta del servidor. ¿puedes poner lo que manda el servidor?

Comment: te refieres a lo que regresa en el data? ya lo puse